# go-ethereum clique stop mining after one block, each node

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, mining, private-blockchain, geth-clique

After a whole day trying, it's time to ask.

I have 14 nodes using go-ethereum that used to work just fine.

I generated 14 accounts, inserted them in signers and voters in the genesis file, created the relative folders on all the nodes with the keystore, started one by one and this thing happens.

I start the first one and mine 1 block then stops. Expected. I start the 2nd one, addPeer on the first one and on the 2nd one, it seals the 2nd block then stops. Weird. Same goes until the 5th node (then i stopped).

Basically, every node seal 1 block and then is not eligible. But neither the others are eligible.

The genesis.json is:

```
    {
  "config": {
    "chainId": 85,
    "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "eip150Block": 0,
    "eip150Hash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "eip155Block": 0,
    "eip158Block": 0,
    "byzantiumBlock": 0,
    "constantinopleBlock": 0,
    "clique": {
      "period": 3,
      "epoch": 30
    }
  },
  "nonce": "0x0",
  "timestamp": "1648228589",
  "extraData": "0x4b4c435f4b4149424100000000000000",
  "signers": [
    "0x4fD06E94C5e39a2B69c412a874b0e37bFD7cBA27",
    "0x6Ed99ce47dDb2d077050E9Eb64030a4cE6012093",
    "0x3766611C716e0E476C5731C7Ef5541EE73ce775A",
    "0xC121b02B293644bc5BAd33a4Ebe4766c92f6Ee17",
    "0xC1a22ddCee5d6049c44340c15f1731A581c2E314",
    "0x03eae6B342243a7909Ba0c23422c3A71C333FacE",
    "0xFD1F7F61eF3dA1fAdba5999A6B39B3399d898f60",
    "0xeDA51A4569414ac317fe55E95e2db2F88C527A9d",
    "0xC7799b25ea8Ae5FCa9dA394b153bD028DbCEd86C",
    "0x85AD12f6909E212fB8ddcE8112328C68022e2e30",
    "0x34682A6E1C06308263d80fF2CE95353486627364",
    "0x8E8A75a3904E24e244bC1976985504A696fBAaad",
    "0x39BAA2039c16030DA9906908C859B48Eff1C32f6",
    "0xC07Eb9409ed99858995c4E2B71b9Cf464C1f1FF0"

  ],
  "voters": [
    "0x4fD06E94C5e39a2B69c412a874b0e37bFD7cBA27",
    "0x6Ed99ce47dDb2d077050E9Eb64030a4cE6012093",
    "0x3766611C716e0E476C5731C7Ef5541EE73ce775A",
    "0xC121b02B293644bc5BAd33a4Ebe4766c92f6Ee17",
    "0xC1a22ddCee5d6049c44340c15f1731A581c2E314",
    "0x03eae6B342243a7909Ba0c23422c3A71C333FacE",
    "0xFD1F7F61eF3dA1fAdba5999A6B39B3399d898f60",
    "0xeDA51A4569414ac317fe55E95e2db2F88C527A9d",
    "0xC7799b25ea8Ae5FCa9dA394b153bD028DbCEd86C",
    "0x85AD12f6909E212fB8ddcE8112328C68022e2e30",
    "0x34682A6E1C06308263d80fF2CE95353486627364",
    "0x8E8A75a3904E24e244bC1976985504A696fBAaad",
    "0x39BAA2039c16030DA9906908C859B48Eff1C32f6",
    "0xC07Eb9409ed99858995c4E2B71b9Cf464C1f1FF0"

  ],
  "signer": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "gasLimit": "2100000",
  "difficulty": "1",
  "mixHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "alloc": {
    "0x4fD06E94C5e39a2B69c412a874b0e37bFD7cBA27": {
              "balance": "0x43DACAF91C1A84FF08000000"
  },
  "0x6Ed99ce47dDb2d077050E9Eb64030a4cE6012093": {
            "balance": "0x43DACAF91C1A84FF08000000"
},
    "0x3766611C716e0E476C5731C7Ef5541EE73ce775A": {
  "balance": "0x43DACAF91C1A84FF08000000"
  },
      "0xC121b02B293644bc5BAd33a4Ebe4766c92f6Ee17": {
"balance": "0x43DACAF91C1A84FF08000000"
    },
    "0xC1a22ddCee5d6049c44340c15f1731A581c2E314": {
  "balance": "0x43DACAF91C1A84FF08000000"
      },
      "0x03eae6B342243a7909Ba0c23422c3A71C333FacE": {
"balance": "0x43DACAF91C1A84FF08000000"
    },
"0xFD1F7F61eF3dA1fAdba5999A6B39B3399d898f60": {
      "balance": "0x43DACAF91C1A84FF08000000"
      },
  "0xeDA51A4569414ac317fe55E95e2db2F88C527A9d": {
    "balance": "0x43DACAF91C1A84FF08000000"
},
"0xC7799b25ea8Ae5FCa9dA394b153bD028DbCEd86C": {
      "balance": "0x43DACAF91C1A84FF08000000"
  },
  "0x85AD12f6909E212fB8ddcE8112328C68022e2e30": {
    "balance": "0x43DACAF91C1A84FF08000000"
},
    "0x34682A6E1C06308263d80fF2CE95353486627364": {
  "balance": "0x43DACAF91C1A84FF08000000"
  },
      "0x8E8A75a3904E24e244bC1976985504A696fBAaad": {
"balance": "0x43DACAF91C1A84FF08000000"
    },
    "0x39BAA2039c16030DA9906908C859B48Eff1C32f6": {
  "balance": "0x43DACAF91C1A84FF08000000"
      },
      "0xC07Eb9409ed99858995c4E2B71b9Cf464C1f1FF0": {
"balance": "0x43DACAF91C1A84FF08000000"
    }
,
    "0xCbeb3C6aEC7040e4949F22234573bd06B31DE83b" : {
    "balance":"0x43DACAF91C1A84FF08000000"
    }
  },
  "number": "0x0",
  "gasUsed": "0x0",
  "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
}
```

I think i used the same commands (init genesis and then run ethereum client with the various options) and i think they are right otherwise they would not sign a block (i think). Note that the block mined is progressive, the 4th mine block n 4, 5th n 5 and so on